# Dynamicaly declaring 2D array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pthreads, multidimensional-array

I have created a 2D array in my main function and want to update it in another function . As per my first thought I need to declare the Array dynamically , but the problem is that the dimension should also be dynamic -

following is what I am trying -

```
int l;
int m;
int n;

void *Hello(void* rank); // Prototype of a thread function

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{

int l = atoi(argv[2]);  
int m = atoi(argv[3]);  
int n = atoi(argv[4]);  

int A[l][m];

 pthread_create(&myThreads[thread_id], NULL,Hello, (void*)thread_id);
}

void *Hello(void* rank)
{ }
```

I want to update Array A from *Hello function , please advice me for right implementation.

Answer (score 3):

First note that a 2-D array is not serializable, so as other answers recommend, a 1-D array may be a better approach in your case. Here is the naive implementation:

```
static int l, m, n; // static: local to compilation unit
int **A;

void *Hello(void* rank); // Prototype of a thread function

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{

l = atoi(argv[2]);  
m = atoi(argv[3]);  
n = atoi(argv[4]);  

A = new int*[l]; // remember to free this!
for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
    A[i] = new int[m];
}

 pthread_create(&myThreads[thread_id], NULL,Hello, (void*)thread_id);
}

void *Hello(void* rank)
{ }
```

Here is another, with a serializable 1-D array to hold the data:

```
static int l, m, n; // static: local to compilation unit
int **A, *A_data;    

void *Hello(void* rank); // Prototype of a thread function

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{

l = atoi(argv[2]);  
m = atoi(argv[3]);  
n = atoi(argv[4]);  

A_data = new int[l*m]; // remember to free this!
for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
    A[i] = &A_data[i*l];
}

 pthread_create(&myThreads[thread_id], NULL,Hello, (void*)thread_id);
}

void *Hello(void* rank)
{ }
```

Let us know if you have any questions. :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response . I tried the first solution , its showing the error of "Segmentation failed" , might be its due to ur comment of "Remember to free this" , where and how should i free

Comment: Segmentation fault could be because, you might be going beyond the memory you have allocated. It has nothing to do with free, at least for now.

Answer (score 2):

Bi-dimensional arrays aren't that common in C++: usually it simpler (and often better) to just have a mono-dimensional array and use it to store all your data:

```
int *A = new int[ l*m ];
// A[i][j] == A[ i*l + j%l ]
```

Also, it's usually a good practice to avoid raw memory allocations in C++: rather use `std::vector` or something other with the semantics of an array:

```
std::vector<int> A( l*m );
// A[i][j] == A[ i*l + j%l ]
```

or, if for some reasons you really need a bi-dimensional array:

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > A( l, std::vector<int>(m) );
// A is a vector of l vectors of m ints
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should allocate the memory for the 2D array in the heap:

```
int **A = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * l);
/* Error checking */
int i;
for(i = 0; i < l; ++i)
    A[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * m);
```

note that the array isn't in contiguous region of memory.
then you need pass the `A` to the `Hello()` using the fourth parameter like this:

```
pthread_create(&myThreads[thread_id], NULL, Hello, (void*)A);
```

then in the function `Hello()`, cast the `void*` back to `int**`

```
int **array = (int**)rank;
```

after that, you can update Array `A` from `Hello()` function.

Here is an example without any error checking:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int l,m;

void *Hello(void* rank); // Prototype of a thread function

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{

        l = atoi(argv[2]);
        m = atoi(argv[3]);
        int **A = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * l);
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i <m; ++i)
                A[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * m);

        A[0][0] = 3;
        pthread_t tid;
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL,Hello, (void*)A);
        pthread_join(tid, NULL);
        return 0;
}

void *Hello(void* rank)
{
        int **array = (int**)rank;
        printf("%d\t", array[0][0]);
        array[0][0] = 4;

        printf("%d\t", array[0][0]);
        return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not trying to make askew array;
how about creating a one d array and accessing it in two dimensional fashion.

```
int l;
int m;
int n;

#define idx(i,j) i*m+j

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{

    int l = atoi(argv[2]);
    int m = atoi(argv[3]);
    int n = atoi(argv[4]);

    int *A=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*l*m);
    memset(A,0,sizeof(int)*l*m);

    // Use the array like this
    // A[idx(i,j)]=10;

}
```

Comment: Beware of that macro: it will only work in scopes where `m` is defined (and has the right type and value!).
A better idea would be to use a function, and then store in a struct the array pointer and its length, but that's way too C-style: just use `std::vector` at that point!

Comment: I won't advice a beginner diving straight to STL containers, when he has difficulty grasping the intricacies of dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: I wouldn't advise a beginner to dive straight into the pitfalls of dynamic memory allocation when he can just use the safe, simple-to-use Standard C++ containers.

Comment: Its definitely safe, Though you miss the chance to learn if you stick to being safe!!